# SQL - Create a pivot-table like table filling columns with values from other columns

Tags: sql, pivot-table, transpose, flags

I have a table like in SQL like:

```
Id flag_0 doc date
1  1      1   d1
1  1      2   d2
1  1      3   d3
2  0      1   d4
2  0      2   d5
```

I want a query to reach the following table:

```
Id flag_0 doc_1 doc_2 doc_3
1  1      d1     d2   d3 
2  0      d4     d5   nan (or missing)
```

Comment: Which Database you are using ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pivot the given table in generalised sql query as [in this demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/ISoX7ZUP)

```
SELECT 
    Id, 
    flag_0,
    MAX(CASE WHEN doc = 1 THEN date END) AS doc_1,
    MAX(CASE WHEN doc = 2 THEN date END) AS doc_2,
    MAX(CASE WHEN doc = 3 THEN date END) AS doc_3
FROM 
    MyTable
GROUP BY 
    Id, flag_0
Order by Id;
```

This shall give you the output as :

```
Id  flag_0  doc_1   doc_2   doc_3
1   True    d1      d2      d3
2   False   d4      d5      null
```

if the date value do not exist; you can mark it as `nan` or `missing` in MYSQL using IFNULL function [as in this demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/JYwTVFNH) :

```
SELECT 
    Id, 
    flag_0,
    IFNULL(MAX(CASE WHEN doc = 1 THEN date END), 'nan') AS doc_1,
    IFNULL(MAX(CASE WHEN doc = 2 THEN date END), 'nan') AS doc_2,
    IFNULL(MAX(CASE WHEN doc = 3 THEN date END), 'nan') AS doc_3
FROM 
    MyTable
GROUP BY 
    Id, flag_0;
```

Output :

```
Id  flag_0  doc_1   doc_2   doc_3
 1  True    d1      d2      d3
 2  False   d4      d5      nan
```

If you are using SQL-Server; You can write the query using [PIVOT operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-using-pivot-and-unpivot?view=sql-server-ver16) as  [in this demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/dxHyTqpk) :

```
SELECT 
    Id, 
    flag_0, 
    ISNULL([1], 'nan') AS doc_1, 
    ISNULL([2], 'nan') AS doc_2, 
    ISNULL([3], 'nan') AS doc_3
FROM 
    (SELECT Id, flag_0, doc, date FROM MyTable) AS SourceTable
PIVOT 
(
    MAX(date) FOR doc IN ([1], [2], [3])
) AS PivotTable
Order by Id;
```

Output :

```
Id  flag_0  doc_1   doc_2   doc_3
 1  True    d1      d2      d3
 2  False   d4      d5      nan
```

> is there a way to create the columns doc automatically. I have about
> 40 different docs, My table has over 1M rows

The below solution shall work for you. [Here is a demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/0KqwBLbw).

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX);
DECLARE @query AS NVARCHAR(MAX);

SELECT @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(doc) 
                    from MyTable
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

SET @query = 'SELECT Id, flag_0, ' + @cols + ' from 
            (
                select Id, flag_0, doc, date
                from MyTable
            ) x
            pivot 
            (
                MAX(date)
                for doc in (' + @cols + ')
            ) p 
            order by Id'

EXECUTE(@query);
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, but is there a way to create the columns doc automatically. I have about 40 different docs

Comment: I am using SQL server Management Studio. My table has over 1M rows.  The database if from my company, and I can share just part of the table , but I dont know how to do it here.